# Saving Unicode characters in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a CMS written in ASP.NET using VB.NET and I am having problems saving Unicode characters to the database. Here's the situation:

The web page seems to send the characters fine via an AJAX request (using jQuery), at least according to Firebug it seems that the POST is sent fine I can see the characters in there as they should be (ie, not screwed up). When I look in the database instead of the non-english character I see a questionmark inside the little black diamond, you know the character. I know it's not the database since a) the field is set to NText and b) I can insert that same value directly into the DB via SQL Manager in a manual query. The database is MS SQL 2005.

So the problem must be in between, correct? I am specifically declaring the param on the insert query as NText:

```
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@FieldContent", SqlDbType.NText).Value = FieldContent
```

and in web.confing I have encoding set as:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

I've googledhigh and low and cannot find any other solutions than the ones I've tried already. Any help is greatly apreciated.

Comment: Forgot to say - the AJAX request has a content-type header of "text/html; charset=utf-8" so I have even less reason to suspect AJAX not sending properly.

Comment: Can you reliably reproduce a scenario where non-Latin text is sent to the server and incorrectly stored or retrieved?

Comment: Have you seen what the data looks like when you query it back out of the DB and display it on a web page?  The data/text might still be fine.  Sometimes SSMS has difficulty picking the right encoding set for displaying data.

Comment: @Dai - if understood you correctly then yes, every time I try to save non-latin characters via the CMS interface they turn out as this character in the DB. Like I said, the POST looks fine in Firebug, so I believe it sending fine. If you have a more reliable way of testing it let me know.

Comment: @tgolisch - It displays back in the CMS and on the pages both screwed up. The pages inside the cms don't have explicitly declared encoding but Firefox seems to recognize them as UTF-8 and the website front end pages are explicitly declared as UTF-8. On neither of them do the non-latin chars come up as they should.

Comment: Have you tried larger encoding schemes like UTF-16?  I've heard that it is usually a better match for NTEXT/NVARCHAR.

Comment: I'm not familiar with UTF-16. You mean use that as the encoding for the pages displaying the character or something else?

Comment: Do you think it could be something server-related? Either a setting in IIS, or .NET? I would think what's in web.config would take precedence over machine-level settings, so it shouldn't be .NET, but figured I'd ask.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FieldContent", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1024).Value = FieldContent;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but no go. Same result, plus the reduced size of the variable cuts off some the longer fields when entering it.